# Avoid creation of styles if `validates_attachment_content_type` fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using the Paperclip gem to manage file uploads in a Rails 3 app.  I have just added

```
validates_attachment_content_type :logo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'], :message => "should be \"PNG, GIF, or JPG\""
```

to my model, and it seems to work except that I have 4 styles to be called on uploaded images and they seem to be being called even though validation fails.

Here are the validation errors that are returned...

```
Logo content type should be "PNG, GIF, or JPG"    Logo /var/folders/cT/cTTe57AGGBiLXq0PUS+RBU+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20110509-3068-ti9gja.doc is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
Logo /var/folders/cT/cTTe57AGGBiLXq0PUS+RBU+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20110509-3068-ti9gja.doc is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
Logo /var/folders/cT/cTTe57AGGBiLXq0PUS+RBU+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20110509-3068-ti9gja.doc is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
Logo /var/folders/cT/cTTe57AGGBiLXq0PUS+RBU+++TI/-Tmp-/stream20110509-3068-ti9gja.doc is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
```

How can I stop the styles from processing (or attempting to do so)?

Not sure if it matters, but the images are stored in Amazon s3.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a known issue in Paperclip that no-one has fixed. There was an [Github issue on it](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/409) but it was closed.

One alternative would be to validate the type using `before_post_process`. Something along the lines of:

```
class Foobar
  before_post_process :check_content_type

  def check_content_type
    return ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'].include?(logo.file_type)
  end
end
```

That should stop the processing if the file does not fit into those content types.